# Geometric multiplicity of the largest eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let 
$$A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 2f & 0 \\
    2f & b & 3f \\
    0 & 3f & c \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,f$ are real numbers and $f\neq 0$. The geometric multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue of $A$ equals ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found the eigenvalues? Please show us your work.