# Geometric multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
 a  &  2f  &  0  \\
 2f &  b   & 3f  \\
  0 &  3f  &  c  
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $f$ are real numbers and $f\neq 0$. Find the geometric multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

I don't think I have to use the characteristic equation. Or do I?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You do have a math editor. It is Latex. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: This same question was asked a couple of weeks ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063378/265466) and got no response.

Answer (score 4):

let $\lambda $ be an eigen value then
$$A - \lambda I =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a-\lambda & 2f & 0 \\
    2f & b-\lambda & 3f \\
    0 & 3f & c-\lambda \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
then $ Rank(A-\lambda I )$ = 2 because

Minor wrt $a_{31}$ =  $\begin{vmatrix} 2f & 0 \\
    b-\lambda & 3f \\
  \end{vmatrix} = 6f^{2} \ne 0$ as $ f \ne 0$

So geometric multiplicity of $ \lambda = 3 - Rank(A-\lambda I ) = 1$ for all Eigen Values of this matrix irrespective of $ \lambda$.

Hence the geometric multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue of A also equals 1.

Comment: You have written $N=R$ . I think $N+R=3$  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem.  Principal minor is wrt diagonal entries, I suppose.

Comment: @Widawensen I am new to this forum. Please correct me If I am missing something here
1. $N(A-\lambda I) = Rank(A-\lambda I )$ because Null space here will be equal to rank of the matrix span by $A-\lambda$ right ?
thanks for pointing out mistake for minor. I corrected the same

Comment: From wikipedia - Nullity, the dimension of the kernel of a mathematical operator or null space of a matrix. Nullity is just =1 in this case, rank =2.

Comment: Yes got your point. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: O.k. Now answer is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

We can check the matrix for some values (matrix is symmetric so it has only real eigenvalues)

Substitute for example $a=b=c=f=1$.
For this you have $λ_1 = 1 + \sqrt{13}$, $λ_2 = 1 - \sqrt{13}$ , $λ_3=1$.

More generally  for $a=b=c=n$ and $f $
 (matrix of the form $nI+fB$ where $B= \begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  2  &  0  \\
 2 &  0   & 3  \\
  0 &  3  &  0  
\end{bmatrix}$)

you have $λ_1 =  n+f\sqrt{13}$, $λ_2 = n -f\sqrt{13}$ , $λ_3=n$.

Evidently at least for some pattern of values multiplicity is just  $1$.

Comment: See also for eigendecomposition of sym. matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices